# Unable to upgradeto new Admob account

Tags: paypal, admob

I am facing an issue as my payment seems to be not processed with paypal.

I came to know that admob has created new interface but I am unable to switch to new interface asI dont see any option of upgrading in my account as mentioned in this video.

https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/3077517?ref_topic=3011419&rd=1

Can somebody help me out that is there any issue with Paypal and how I can switch to new interface.

Thanks,

Amandeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The roll out of the new Admob dashboard (user interface) is occurring in stages. It has not yet come to some countries. Be patient.

Not sure about Paypal. I get my payments direct into my bank account.

Answer (score 2):

You can only upgrade if they have rolled it out in your country, in which case you'll see a banner at the top of your AdMob site: "We have launched a new version of AdMob! >Upgrade< Learn more".

If you are running AdBlocker on Chrome you have to prevent it blocking ads on the new site or else all you will see is a blank screen.

In this case you will see a little 1 next to to the AdBlock hand so left click the hand, and choose "Don't run on pages on this domain".

Answer (score 0):

Paypal is not supported any more in some countries (Europe, North America).

Comment: I am from India and Paypal was supported in India, but the concern is admob has launched new interface but I don't see any option for upgrading to new interface.

Answer (score 0):

I am also confused about how to upgrade to new Admob as there is no option to upgrade. But I got my payment initiated mail just now.